# Redirection Form from product page to checkout page in shopify

Tags: shopify, product, checkout

Write form code that follows the shopify standards for product page that directs the customer straight to checkout page with form field data and product properties attached in incorporated on checkout page.

The form has the following fields:

```
Discount code
First Name
Last Name
Address
Address 2
Phone
City
State
Email
Zip Code
Rush my order submit button
```

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
<form id="checkout-form">
    <label for="discount-code">Discount Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="discount-code" name="discountCode" ><br>

    <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName" required><br>

    <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName" required><br>

    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required><br>

    <label for="address-2">Address 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address-2" name="address2"><br>

    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required><br>

    <label for="state">State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" required><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

    <label for="zip-code">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip-code" name="zipCode" required><br>

    <button type="submit" id="rush-order-submit">Rush My Order</button>
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('checkout-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get form data
        const formData = {
            discountCode: document.getElementById('discount-code').value,
            firstName: document.getElementById('first-name').value,
            lastName: document.getElementById('last-name').value,
            address: document.getElementById('address').value,
            address2: document.getElementById('address-2').value,
            phone: document.getElementById('phone').value,
            city: document.getElementById('city').value,
            state: document.getElementById('state').value,
            email: document.getElementById('email').value,
            zipCode: document.getElementById('zip-code').value
        };

        // Get product properties (example values, replace with actual product data)
        const productProperties = {
            productName: '{{ product.title }}',
            price: {{product.price}},
            quantity: 1
        };

        // Redirect to Shopify checkout page with form and product properties as query parameters
        const checkoutUrl = '/checkout'; // Update with your Shopify checkout URL
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({...formData, ...productProperties}).toString();
        window.location.href = `${checkoutUrl}?${queryParams}`;
    });
</script>
```